# homology of rings with enough idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, homology-cohomology, idempotents

Is there a homology/cohomology theory defined for rings with enough idempotents, which are also derived functors?

Comment: Derived functors usually arise from left/right exact functors. Can you think of any interesting such functors?

Comment: I have Tor and Ext functors in mind. What I wish to know is, if there is a projective resolution of R, where R is a ring with enough idempotents.

Comment: For those who don't know, "enough idempotents" is a formal condition, not a vague term. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra) . I don't know the answer to this question, but I spent some time thinking about rings with local units (a weaker condition) and it is often a good idea to study not all modules over such rings, but only modules $M$ for which there exists an idempotent $e$ which acts as the identity on $M$.

Comment: See "Morita equivalence for rings with local units" https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927878308822881 for a paper which does non-trivial things with this.

Comment: "Basic Module Theory for General Rings" https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2010.530328 discusses issues of homological algebra, although I don't have time to see exactly what it says about them.